# Update a column using values from another column that match a specific criteria

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I want to drop all the entries from the field `customers_fax` and then move all numbers beginning `07` from the `customers_telephone` field to the `customers_fax` field.

The table structure is below

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `zen_customers` (
`customers_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`customers_gender` char(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`customers_firstname` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`customers_lastname` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`customers_dob` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0001-01-01 00:00:00',
`customers_email_address` varchar(96) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`customers_nick` varchar(96) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`customers_default_address_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`customers_telephone` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`customers_fax` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
`customers_password` varchar(40) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`customers_newsletter` char(1) DEFAULT NULL,
`customers_group_pricing` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`customers_email_format` varchar(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'TEXT',
`customers_authorization` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`customers_referral` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`customers_paypal_payerid` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`customers_paypal_ec` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
 ) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=18346 ;
```

Dropping any existing data is simple enough as I will just do

```
UPDATE zen_customers SET customers_fax = ''
```

I've no idea how to move only numbers starting with `07` to the `customers_fax` field ensuring they stay with the relevant `customers_id`.

Is there a simple way to do this as an SQL query only?

Comment: You just need to run an update statement.  Have it put the value of one field into the other field.  Then run another update statement to set the original field blank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
UPDATE zen_customers 
SET customers_fax = customers_telephone
WHERE customers_telephone like '07%'
```

Comment: As this was the first answer in, this is the one I tried and it worked perfectly. I finished off with UPDATE zen_customers 
SET customers_telephone = ' '
WHERE customers_fax like '07%' to remove the original entries. Many thanks for a quick and precise answer.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
UPDATE zen_customers 
SET customers_fax = customers_telephone 
WHERE customers_telephone LIKE '07%';
```

But if you want to test on one customer to be sure it does what you expect, you can always run this update query on a specific user that have a '07' telephone number:

```
UPDATE zen_customers 
SET customers_fax = customers_telephone 
WHERE customers_id = N;
```

Where N is an integer.

Comment: hey, about the answer you've deleted: take a look: `sql = "SELECT DATE_FORMAT(created_at,'%Y%m'), count(*) FROM users GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(created_at,'%Y%m')"`  `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql).to_a` #=>  `[["201504", 90], ["201505", 133], ["201506", 131], ["201507", 28], ["201508", 45], ["201509", 6]]` which is the simple count grouping by month.

Comment: @Andrey Oh ok I see! My entire fault, I red your question too fast. The problem is more interesting though. If I find a solution, I will post it.

Comment: You are more than welcome to post new answer, if you have an idea of how to achieve what I need :) Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE zen_customers a, zen_customers b 
SET a.customers_fax=b.customers_telephone 
WHERE 
    a.customers_id=b.customers_id 
    AND b.customers_telephone LIKE '07%'
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `case` expression to conditionally set `customers_fax` to `customers_telephone` if `customers_telephone` starts with `07`, and `''` if it doesn't:

```
UPDATE zen_customers 
SET customers_fax = CASE 
                      WHEN customers_telephone LIKE '07%' THEN customers_telephone 
                      ELSE '' 
                    END;
```

This would save you from having to run two different updates.